# Add a sitemap provider at runtime in asp.net (MVC framework)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitemap

I'm building a regionalized site each region has it own sitemap and own content.
The regions can be added at runtime.
Is there any way to add a sitemap provider at runtime?

I need multiple site map providers at once so that I can leverage the mvcsitemap without to many changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your custom site map provider in order to take  information from database or from another file than web.sitemap.

Example of database sitemap: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163657.aspx

Comment: But I need few different sitemap at once. Rebuilding the sitemap at each request could be quite resource consuming.

Comment: It was jsut an example to show you how to build your own provider. You can build one that will deal with different sitemap

Answer (score 0):

There is an MVC sitemap provider available at: http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/

I'm using it for a project right now.  It has caching functionality built into the code so your overhead shouldn't be too bad.  Even in debug mode running the sitemap for every request takes < 100 ms so I wouldn't worry about performance.

Your performance concerns are a little yagni too.  "Could be quite resource consuming".  You don't know so your just prematurely optimizing.

Comment: I'm currently using mvcsitemap with few modification. But the requirements were changed (I need multiple _different_ site maps). I'm looking for a way to leverage mvcsitemap and still meet the customer needs.

Comment: Re. Performance concerns - you are right. I've edited the question